# (Solved) Why is smtp not sending email on published Blazor Server app?

Tags: blazor-server-side, smtpclient, system.net.mail

I have an smtp (System.Net.Mail) issue. On debug mode (developing) my smtp code runs perfectly. No errors. But when I publish the Blazor App an error occurs. Upon investigation I got this error Object reference not set to an instance of an object. It seems my email address variable is Null.

My code below:

```
  @code {
    //=============== email message ================
    private string Message { get; set; } = "";
    private string emailAddress { get; set; } = "";

    //==============
    bool isSubmitting;

    //SF Dialog Declations
    SfDialog GenericDialog;
    SfDialog DialogDelete;
    SfDialog DialogEndEMR;
    SfDialog DialogRemoveResponder;
    SfDialog DialogAddEditCall;
    SfDialog DialogAddEditResponder;
    private string GenericMessage = "";

    //Call Variable declarations
    IEnumerable<CallModel> calls;
    private int SelectedCallID;
    CallModel AddEditCall = new CallModel();
    string HeaderText = "";
    string DeleteItem = "";
    string DisableText = "";
    string EndEMRText = "";
    //string DeleteResponderText = "";
    int isCompleted = 0;
    string ResponderName = "";


    //Responder Variable declarations
    IEnumerable<ResponderModel> responders;
    private int SelectedResponderID;
    ResponderModel AddEditResponder = new ResponderModel();

    string RefNo = "";

    //Duty Variable declarations
    IEnumerable<DutyModel> availableEmrs;

    //sfgrid variable declarations
    private List<ItemModel> Toolbaritems = new List<ItemModel>();

    //sfgrid variable declarations
    private List<ItemModel> Toolbaritems2 = new List<ItemModel>();

    //====== synfuxsion ====================
    private DialogEffect AnimationEffect = DialogEffect.Zoom;

    //Priority Variable Declarations
    IEnumerable<PriorityModel> priorities;
    private int SelectedPriorityID;

    //NOE Variable Declarations
    IEnumerable<NatureOfEmergencyModel> natureOfEmergencies;
    private int SelectedNatureOfEmergencyID;

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        //Populate Priority list
        priorities = await PriorityService.PriorityList();

        //Populate NOE
        natureOfEmergencies = await NatureOfEmergencyService.NatureOfEmergencyList();

        //Populate Call list
        calls = await CallService.CallList(DateTime.Today);

        //Populate responder list
        responders = await ResponderService.ResponderList(SelectedCallID);

        //Populate toolbaritems for SFGrid
        Toolbaritems.Add(new ItemModel() { Text = "Add", TooltipText = "Add a new Call", PrefixIcon = "e-add" });
        Toolbaritems.Add(new ItemModel() { Text = "Edit", TooltipText = "Edit selected Call", PrefixIcon = "e-edit" });
        Toolbaritems.Add(new ItemModel() { Text = "Cancel", TooltipText = "Cancel selected Call", PrefixIcon = "e-delete" });
        Toolbaritems.Add(new ItemModel() { Text = "End EMR", TooltipText = "End Emergency", PrefixIcon = "e-cancel" });

        //Populate toolbaritems2 for SFGrid
        Toolbaritems2.Add(new ItemModel() { Text = "Add", TooltipText = "Add Responders", PrefixIcon = "e-add" });
        Toolbaritems2.Add(new ItemModel() { Text = "Delete", TooltipText = "Delete Responder", PrefixIcon = "e-delete" });

        //Refresh deployed responders
        StartTimer();
    }

    //============ Grid Toolbaritems Add Edit Delete Code SHOW ONLY ============================
    public async Task ToolbarClickHandler(Syncfusion.Blazor.Navigations.ClickEventArgs args)
    {
        if (args.Item.Text == "Add")
        {
            SelectedCallID = 0;
            AddEditCall = new CallModel();
            HeaderText = "Add Call";
            await this.DialogAddEditCall.ShowAsync();
        }

        if (args.Item.Text == "Edit")
        {
            if (SelectedCallID == 0)
            {
                GenericMessage = "Please select a Call to Edit.";
                await this.GenericDialog.ShowAsync();
            }
            else
            {
                //populate AddEditCall object for data editing
                HeaderText = "Edit Call";
                AddEditCall = await CallService.Call_GetOne(SelectedCallID);
                await this.DialogAddEditCall.ShowAsync();
            }

        }
        if (args.Item.Text == "Cancel")
        {
            if (isCompleted != 1)
            {
                //code for deleting
                if (SelectedCallID > 0)
                {
                    await this.DialogDelete.ShowAsync();
                }
                else
                {
                    //no record selected
                    GenericMessage = "Please select a Call to Cancel";
                    await this.GenericDialog.ShowAsync();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                GenericMessage = "Completed Emergency Call cannot be cancelled.";
                await this.GenericDialog.ShowAsync();
            }
        }
        if (args.Item.Text == "End EMR")
        {
            //code for deleting
            if (SelectedCallID > 0)
            {
                await this.DialogEndEMR.ShowAsync();
            }
            else
            {
                //no record selected
                GenericMessage = "Please select a Call to End EMR";
                await this.GenericDialog.ShowAsync();
            }
        }
    }

    //====== code to get CallID from the Grid ===================
    public async Task RowSelectHandler(RowSelectEventArgs<CallModel> args)
    {

        //{args.Data} returns the current selected records.
        if (args != null)
        {
            SelectedCallID = args.Data.CallID;
            DeleteItem = args.Data.NameOfCaller;

            RefNo = "Deploying EMR Presonnel to Call Ref No: " + args.Data.CallID + " | Caller: " + args.Data.NameOfCaller;
            EndEMRText = "Caller: " + args.Data.NameOfCaller + " Ref No: " + args.Data.CallID;
            isCompleted = args.Data.isCompleted;

            //Populate responder list
            responders = await ResponderService.ResponderList(SelectedCallID);

            //Populate available EMR's
            availableEmrs = await DutyService.AvailablePersonnelList(SelectedCallID);

            if (args.Data.isCancelled == "Cancelled")
            {
                DisableText = "Enable";
            }
            else
            {
                DisableText = "Cancel";
            }
        }

    }

    //============= Close Generic Dialog ================
    private async Task CloseGenericDialog()
    {
        await this.GenericDialog.HideAsync();
    }

    //===== code for deleting record =============
    public async Task ConfirmDeleteYes()
    {
        if (isCompleted != 1)
        {
            int Success = await CallService.CallDelete(SelectedCallID);

            if (Success != 0)
            {
                GenericMessage = "Call can't be deleted";
                await this.GenericDialog.ShowAsync();
            }

            else
            {
                await this.DialogDelete.HideAsync();
                calls = await CallService.CallList(DateTime.Today);
                SelectedCallID = 0;
                responders = await ResponderService.ResponderList(SelectedCallID);
                StateHasChanged();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            GenericMessage = "Cannot cancel a Completed Emergency Call";
            await this.GenericDialog.ShowAsync();
        }
    }

    //===== code for end emr record =============
    public async Task ConfirmEndEMRYes()
    {
        int Success = await CallService.CallEndEMR(SelectedCallID);

        if (Success != 0)
        {
            GenericMessage = "Somthing went wrong";
            await this.GenericDialog.ShowAsync();
        }
        else
        {
            await this.DialogEndEMR.HideAsync();
            calls = await CallService.CallList(DateTime.Today);
            StateHasChanged();
        }

    }

    //===== code for end emr record =============
    public async Task ConfirmRemoveResponderYes()
    {
        int Success = await ResponderService.ResponderDelete(SelectedResponderID);

        if (Success != 0)
        {
            GenericMessage = "Somthing went wrong";
            await this.GenericDialog.ShowAsync();
        }
        else
        {
            await this.DialogRemoveResponder.HideAsync();
            responders = await ResponderService.ResponderList(SelectedCallID);
            StateHasChanged();
        }

    }

    //==== cancel delete Record ============
    public async void ConfirmDeleteNo()
    {
        await this.DialogDelete.HideAsync();
    }


    //==== cancel End EMR Record ============
    public async void ConfirmEndEMRNo()
    {
        await this.DialogEndEMR.HideAsync();
    }

    //==== cancel End EMR Record ============
    public async void ConfirmRemoveResponderRNo()
    {
        await this.DialogRemoveResponder.HideAsync();
    }

    //====== code add/edit User Record SAVING DATA =====================
    protected async Task CallAddEditSave()
    {
        if (isSubmitting)
            return;

        isSubmitting = true;

        try
        {

            //===== code adding user record if selected userid is 0
            if (SelectedCallID == 0)
            {
                int Success = await CallService.CallInsert(AddEditCall.LocationOfEmergency,
                AddEditCall.MapAddress,
                AddEditCall.NatureOfEmergencyID,
                AddEditCall.InjuriesAndSymptoms,
                AddEditCall.HowManyPeopleInvolved,
                AddEditCall.ConsciousAndBreathing,
                AddEditCall.AreaSituation,
                AddEditCall.SpecialNeedsSituation,
                AddEditCall.NameOfCaller,
                AddEditCall.CallerContactInfo,
                AddEditCall.PriorityID,
                0,
                Global.UserID);

                if (Success != 0)
                {
                    //error
                    GenericMessage = "Something went wrong.";
                    await this.GenericDialog.ShowAsync();
                }
                else
                {
                    await this.DialogAddEditCall.HideAsync();
                    calls = await CallService.CallList(DateTime.Today);
                    this.StateHasChanged();
                }


            }
            else
            {
                int Success = await CallService.CallUpdate(AddEditCall.CallID,
                AddEditCall.LocationOfEmergency,
                AddEditCall.MapAddress,
                AddEditCall.NatureOfEmergencyID,
                AddEditCall.InjuriesAndSymptoms,
                AddEditCall.HowManyPeopleInvolved,
                AddEditCall.ConsciousAndBreathing,
                AddEditCall.AreaSituation,
                AddEditCall.SpecialNeedsSituation,
                AddEditCall.NameOfCaller,
                AddEditCall.CallerContactInfo,
                AddEditCall.PriorityID,
                0,
                Global.UserID);
                if (Success != 0)
                {
                    //error
                    GenericMessage = "Something went wrong";
                    await this.GenericDialog.ShowAsync();
                }
                else
                {
                    await this.DialogAddEditCall.HideAsync();
                    calls = await CallService.CallList(DateTime.Today);
                    this.StateHasChanged();
                }
            }

        }
        finally
        {
            isSubmitting = false;
        }
    }

    //============== Role Combox Code on Change Combobox ===========================
    public void OnChangeNoE(Syncfusion.Blazor.DropDowns.ChangeEventArgs<int, NatureOfEmergencyModel> args)
    {
        SelectedNatureOfEmergencyID = args.ItemData.NatureOfEmergencyID; ;
        this.AddEditCall.NatureOfEmergencyID = SelectedNatureOfEmergencyID;
    }

    //============== Role Combox Code on Change Combobox ===========================
    public void OnChangePriority(Syncfusion.Blazor.DropDowns.ChangeEventArgs<int, PriorityModel> args)
    {
        SelectedPriorityID = args.ItemData.PriorityID; ;
        this.AddEditCall.PriorityID = SelectedPriorityID;
    }

    //Close AddEdit
    private async Task CloseDialogAddEdit()
    {
        await this.DialogAddEditCall.HideAsync();
    }

    //Close AddEdit
    private async Task CloseDialogAddEdit2()
    {
        await this.DialogAddEditResponder.HideAsync();
    }

    //============ Grid Toolbaritems Add Edit Delete Code SHOW ONLY ============================
    public async Task ToolbarClickHandler2(Syncfusion.Blazor.Navigations.ClickEventArgs args)
    {
        if (args.Item.Text == "Add")
        {


            if (isCompleted == 0)
            {
                if (SelectedCallID > 0)
                {
                    //Populate available EMR's
                    availableEmrs = await DutyService.AvailablePersonnelList(SelectedCallID);

                    SelectedResponderID = 0;
                    AddEditResponder = new ResponderModel();
                    HeaderText = "Add Responder";

                    await this.DialogAddEditResponder.ShowAsync();
                }
                else
                {
                    {
                        //no record selected
                        GenericMessage = "Please select a Emergency Call from the grid";
                        await this.GenericDialog.ShowAsync();
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                {
                    //no record selected
                    GenericMessage = "Emergency Call is already completed. No deployment needed.";
                    await this.GenericDialog.ShowAsync();
                }
            }

        }


        if (args.Item.Text == "Delete")
        {
            //code for deleting
            if (SelectedResponderID > 0)
            {
                await this.DialogRemoveResponder.ShowAsync();
            }
            else
            {
                //no record selected
                GenericMessage = "Please select a Responder to Delete";
                await this.GenericDialog.ShowAsync();
            }
        }

    }

    //====== code to get CallID from the Grid ===================
    public void RowSelectHandler2(RowSelectEventArgs<ResponderModel> args)
    {

        //{args.Data} returns the current selected records.
        if (args != null)
        {
            SelectedResponderID = args.Data.ResponderID;
            ResponderName = args.Data.FullName;
        }

    }



    //====== code add/edit emr Record SAVING DATA =====================
    protected async Task ResponderAddEditSave()
    {
        if (isSubmitting)
            return;

        isSubmitting = true;

        try
        {

            var selectedEMR = availableEmrs.Where(p => p.isSelected == true);
            foreach (var emr in selectedEMR)
            {
                int Success = await ResponderService.ResponderInsert(SelectedCallID,
                                                                       emr.DutyID,
                                                                     Global.UserID);
                string emrname = emr.FullName;
                string refno = calls.First().CallID.ToString();
                string calldate = calls.First().CallDate.ToString();
                string natureofemergency = calls.First().NatureOfEmergency; ;
                string location = calls.First().LocationOfEmergency; ;
                string maplocation = calls.First().MapAddress;
                string emralert = "https://emrdispatch.ncst.edu.ph/";

                StringBuilder prompt = new StringBuilder();
                prompt.AppendLine("<p>Email Date : " + DateTime.Today + "</p>");
                prompt.AppendLine("<p>Attention : " + emrname + "</p>");
                prompt.AppendLine("<p>Ref No : " + refno + "</p>");
                prompt.AppendLine("<p>Date of Emergency : " + calldate + "</p>");
                prompt.AppendLine("<p>Nature of Emergency : " + natureofemergency + "</p>");
                prompt.AppendLine("<p>Location : " + location + "</p>");
                prompt.AppendLine("<p>Map Address :"  + maplocation + "</p>");
                prompt.AppendLine("<p>EMR Alert :" + emralert + "</p>");


                Message = prompt.ToString();

                emailAddress = emr.Email;
                SendMail();

                if (Success != 0)
                {
                    //error
                    GenericMessage = "Something went wrong.";
                    await this.GenericDialog.ShowAsync();
                }
                else
                {
                    await this.DialogAddEditResponder.HideAsync();
                    responders = await ResponderService.ResponderList(SelectedCallID);
                    this.StateHasChanged();
                }
            }

        }
        finally
        {
            isSubmitting = false;
        }
    }

    public void CustomizeCallCell(QueryCellInfoEventArgs<CallModel> args)
    {

        if (args.Column.Field == "EMRStatus")
        {
            if (args.Data.EMRStatus == $"<span style=\"color:#17a2b8;font-weight:700;background-color:lightyellow;\">On Going</span>")
            {
                args.Cell.AddClass(new string[] { "blink" });
            }
        }

    }

    public void CustomizeCell(QueryCellInfoEventArgs<ResponderModel> args)
    {

        if (args.Column.Field == "Status")
        {
            if (args.Data.Status == $"<span style=\"color:#17a2b8;font-weight:700;background-color:lightyellow;\">Standing By</span>")
            {
                args.Cell.AddClass(new string[] { "blink" });
            }
        }

    }

    /// <summary>
    /// /TIMER CODE
    /// </summary>


    private Timer timer;

    public void Dispose()
    {
        timer.Dispose();
    }


    private void StartTimer()
    {
        timer = new Timer();
        timer.Interval = 3000;
        timer.Elapsed += OnTimerElapsed;
        timer.Enabled = true;
    }
    private async void OnTimerElapsed(object? sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        responders = await ResponderService.ResponderList(SelectedCallID);
        await InvokeAsync(() =>
        {
            StateHasChanged();
        });

    }

    private void SendMail()
    {
        try
        {
            using (MailMessage mail = new MailMessage())
            {
                mail.From = new MailAddress("fictitiousmail.com");
                mail.To.Add(emailAddress.ToString());
                mail.Subject = "Emergency Call Alert";
                mail.Body = "<div class=\"m-0\">" + Message + "</div>";

                mail.IsBodyHtml = true;

                using (SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587))
                {

                    smtpClient.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("fictitiousmail.com", "asdfasdfasdfagsdfg");
                    smtpClient.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
                    smtpClient.EnableSsl = true;
                    smtpClient.Send(mail);
                    Message = "Mail Sent";
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            Message = ex.Message;
            js.InvokeVoidAsync("alert", Message);
        }
    }

}
```

I cant seem to fix the issue when in debug mode my `emailAddress` variable will store a value from the `emr` object. But when published and hosted to the server the `emailaddress` variable becomes null.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Oliver

Running the Blazor server app on debug mode over and over again gave me no issues. Only after I publish the Blazor Server app gave me an Error (emailAddress = null)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: As we don't know where your data comes from, how are we supposed to know why something is null?

Comment: updated my post above. emailAddress datasource. I assure you my database has valid email addresses. That's why I dont dont understand in debug mode Blazor app runs with no errors. email Addresses has values. Published mode. emailAddress comes up null. Weird!

Comment: Still, it's not a problem of SMTP but of your datasource. I don't know what `DutyService` is or does. But in the end of the day, at least one `emr` you select from from `availableEmrs` does not have a valid email address ...

Comment: I'm using the same database in my development and production. So the invalid email address is not the issue.

Comment: Well obviously following the error `emailaddress` (where is that variable even defined) is null. So it's either already null when it is getting assigned at `emailAddress = emr.Email;` or it is assigned to a null value somewhere else ... However non of this is included in the code you show us ...

Comment: updated my post above. My complete code.

Comment: I see only two assignments to `emailAddress`.  Once in the definition where it is assigned `private string emailAddress { get; set; } = "";` to an empty string, and the other one `emailAddress = emr.Email`, so if `emailAddress` is null, it can only come from at least one `emr.Email`  being null ... So I still believe the problem is in `DutyService` which you don't show ...

Comment: OMG! I should have listened to you (@derpirscher) the first time you said the issue is DutyService. I checked my storedproc, email was not included. My bad. Thanks @derpirscher. Man you are a life saver. lol.

Comment: Voting to close as this was just a simple missing assignment of a value.

Comment: That makes me wonder how that would have worked in development environment???